# Locally L^2 strong convergence implies $H^1$ weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{t\in[-t_0，t_0]}|R_n(t)|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}=0.$$ 
 Can we deduce that $R_n(t)\rightharpoonup 0\;$ in $\,H^1\;$ for any $t\in[-t_0,t_0]\;\;?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Forget about $t$, it's a red herring.  Let $f_n$ be a "triangle" of height $n$ and width $1/n^3$.  Then $f_n \to 0$ in $L^2$ but the $H^1$ norm of $f_n$ tends to infinity, so $f_n$ does not converge weakly in $H^1$ by the uniform boundedness principle.

If you want to bring in $t$, just let $R_n(t) = f_n$ for all $t$.

Comment: what if f_n is H^1 bounded

Comment: @cc250: Then yes.  By Alaoglu, every subsequence of $f_n$ has a further subsequence converging weakly in $H^1$, and the weak limit must be 0 since that is the $L^2$ limit.